# Hook within an exisiting hook?

Tags: commerce, hooks

I have one hook, "hook_form_commerce_checkout_form_alter" and that is modifying something on my checkout process. Within that though I have a switch statement that if true I want to use "hook_commerce_checkout_router" to skip the page. Is this allowed? I can't get any signs of life via DPM. I ran through a bunch of other modules and can't find anything helpful

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already loading the form, your switch statement won't do anything. If you want to skip the page, you'll need to implement `hook_commerce_checkout_router()` in your module so that you can control if it shows up or not.

Comment: Ok thank you but, for all general purposes moving forward is it ok to have a hook within a hook? For example a delete hook?

Comment: You mean to call a hook within a module? e.g.
    MYMODULE_hook_something() {
      module_invoke_all('some_other_hook');
    }

Comment: No let me clarify I have a module that has a hook and then within that hook it calls another hook (like a simple delete or similar)

Comment: It depends on what hook you're calling, but unless you are overriding a hook and you shouldn't be invoking another module's hook within your own code unless there is a darn good reason for doing so.